# Slanted grids in TikZ as a macro?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I'm trying to draw a diagram with slanted grids in it, sort of like the 3D effect given at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/3d-graph-model/

Ideally, I'd like a macro `slantedgrid` so that for example

```
\draw (10,12) \slantedgrid (7,5);
```

or maybe even simply

```
\slantedgrid{10}{12}{7}{5}
```

will draw a grid with all vertical lines slanted at 45 degrees, the lower left corner at (10,12) and with 5+1 horizontal lines and 7+1 vertical (slanted) lines.

My first (and so far only) attempt was to define it with LaTeX "newcommand" as

```
\newcommand{\slantedgrid}[4]{%
  \foreach \x in {#1,#1+1,...,#1+#3} \draw (\x,#2) -- ++(#4,#4);%
  \foreach \y in {#2,#2+1,...,#2+#4} \draw (\y-#4,\y) -- ++(#3,0);%
 }
```

However, all this produces is loads of errors - "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)" - when I bung `slantedgrid{10}{12}{7}{5}` into a `tikzpicture` environment.

Is there any simple method of doing something like this - in particular passing the parameters from a `newcommand` to TikZ's `foreach`?

Comment: Is `\foreach` an essential requirement? As it stands, `\draw [shift={(10,12)}, xslant=tan 45] grid ++(7,5);` seems to do it nicely.

Comment: Gak, arrgh!  `xslant` makes my task almost trivial.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @MarkWibrow You should put your solution in an answer, I almost missed your comment.

Answer (score 3):

If you want still to pass a calculated parameters to `foreach` you can use `pgfmathtruncatemacro`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\slantedgrid}[4]{%
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{#1+#3}
   \foreach \x in {#1,...,\result} \draw (\x,#2) -- ++(#4,#4);%
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{#2+#4}
   \foreach \y in {#2,...,\result} \draw (#1+\y-#2,\y) -- ++(#3,0);%
 }
\slantedgrid{10}{12}{7}{5}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS:
I changed second `foreach` to what I think you had in mind.

Comment: Thanks again!  Yes, I was sure my second `foreach` was incorrect even as I posted it...